# NPM in Maven Build on Jenkins takes forever because of recursive (self-)packaging of module

Tags: maven, jenkins, npm

I am currently facing a performance issue / NPM bug (?) on Jenkins when using it via Maven.

What am I doing:

1. Using https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) to
   install node & npm (if necessary)
2. Install build-tool npm dependencies (e.g. grunt-cli) via npm install
3. Install project npm dependencies (e.g. jquery) into a specific location of the project (using both --global & --prefix )
4. Running some grunt tasks to modify / add the JS depdencies to the project's WAR

The same build takes about 30min on Jenkins (Linux) & 4-5min on local builds (Windows).

During Step 3, npm seems to take very long before actually fetching somehting (verbose npm output here). During that time, NPM seems to create a package.tgz, which under Windows (local) only contains the package.json, while under Linux (Jenkins) it contains recursive copies of project-Dependencies-package-name in a structure like this:

```
 package
 |-lib (+ package.json)
  |-node_modules
    |-project-Dependencies-package-name
      |-lib (+ package.json)
        |-node_modules
          |-project-Dependencies-package-name
            |-lib (+ package.json)
              ...
```

Note that project-Dependencies-package-name only exists because of the package.json to declare the project JS dependencies, that "module" is never actually published or used elsewhere.

```
[ERROR] npm verb addLocalTarball adding from inside cache /usr/local/tomcat/.npm/project-Dependencies-package-name/0.0.1/package.tgz
[ERROR] npm verb correctMkdir /usr/local/tomcat/.npm correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
[ERROR] npm verb afterAdd /usr/local/tomcat/.npm/project-Dependencies-package-name/0.0.1/package/package.json not in flight; writing
[ERROR] npm verb correctMkdir /usr/local/tomcat/.npm correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
[ERROR] npm verb afterAdd /usr/local/tomcat/.npm/project-Dependencies-package-name/0.0.1/package/package.json written
[ERROR] npm info install project-Dependencies-package-name@0.0.1 into /appl/tomcat-version/.jenkins/jobs/my-continous-build-workspace/workspace/my-project/src/main/javascript/dependencies/lib
[ERROR] npm info installOne project-Dependencies-package-name@0.0.1
[ERROR] npm verb installOne of project-Dependencies-package-name to /appl/tomcat-version/.jenkins/jobs/my-continous-build-workspace/workspace/my-project/src/main/javascript/dependencies/lib not in flight; installing
[ERROR] npm verb correctMkdir /usr/local/tomcat/.npm/_locks correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
[ERROR] npm verb lock using /usr/local/tomcat/.npm/_locks/compassDienste-Dependenc-39458a7b01736484.lock for /appl/tomcat-version/.jenkins/jobs/my-continous-build-workspace/workspace/my-project/src/main/javascript/dependencies/lib/node_modules/project-Dependencies-package-name
[ERROR] npm verb unbuild lib/node_modules/project-Dependencies-package-name
[ERROR] npm info preuninstall project-Dependencies-package-name@0.0.1
[ERROR] npm info uninstall project-Dependencies-package-name@0.0.1
[ERROR] npm verb unbuild rmStuff project-Dependencies-package-name@0.0.1 from /appl/tomcat-version/.jenkins/jobs/my-continous-build-workspace/workspace/my-project/src/main/javascript/dependencies/lib/node_modules
[ERROR] npm info postuninstall project-Dependencies-package-name@0.0.1
[ERROR] npm verb gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking /appl/tomcat-version/.jenkins/jobs/my-continous-build-workspace/workspace/my-project/src/main/javascript/dependencies/lib/node_modules/project-Dependencies-package-name

[ERROR] npm verb tar unpack /usr/local/tomcat/.npm/project-Dependencies-package-name/0.0.1/package.tgz
[ERROR] npm verb tar unpacking to /appl/tomcat-version/.jenkins/jobs/my-continous-build-workspace/workspace/my-project/src/main/javascript/dependencies/lib/node_modules/project-Dependencies-package-name
[ERROR] npm verb gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking /appl/tomcat-version/.jenkins/jobs/my-continous-build-workspace/workspace/my-project/src/main/javascript/dependencies/lib/node_modules/project-Dependencies-package-name

[ERROR] npm verb write writing to /appl/tomcat-version/.jenkins/jobs/my-continous-build-workspace/workspace/my-project/src/main/javascript/dependencies/lib/node_modules/project-Dependencies-package-name/package.json
[ERROR] npm info preinstall project-Dependencies-package-name@0.0.1
[ERROR] npm verb readDependencies loading dependencies from /appl/tomcat-version/.jenkins/jobs/my-continous-build-workspace/workspace/my-project/src/main/javascript/dependencies/lib/node_modules/project-Dependencies-package-name/package.json
[ERROR] npm verb readDependencies loading dependencies from /appl/tomcat-version/.jenkins/jobs/my-continous-build-workspace/workspace/my-project/src/main/javascript/dependencies/lib/node_modules/project-Dependencies-package-name/package.json
```

Config files:

pom.xml of a module in the project, plugin -> executions section

Step 1 Installing node & npm if not installed on the current machine

```
<execution>
  <id>install node</id>
  <goals>
    <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
  </goals>
  <configuration>
    <nodeVersion>v4.6.0</nodeVersion>
  </configuration>
</execution>
```

Step 2 Install dev / build-tool dependencies (required for grunt, see below)

```
<execution>
  <id>npm install</id>
  <goals>
    <goal>npm</goal>
  </goals>
</execution>
```

Step 3 Install actual project dependencies

```
<execution>
  <id>install project js dependencies</id>
  <goals>
    <goal>npm</goal>
  </goals>
  <configuration>
    <workingDirectory>src/main/javascript/dependencies</workingDirectory>
    <arguments>install --production --global --prefix ./ --userconfig=.npmrc</arguments>
  </configuration>
</execution>
```

Step 4 Do something more with the fetched dependencies (fine from here on)

```
<execution>
  <id>grunt build</id>
  <goals>
    <goal>grunt</goal>
  </goals>
</execution>
```

.npmrc

```
registry = https://nexus.company.tld/nexus/content/groups/company-npm/
```

build-tools package.json

```
{
  "name": "build-tools",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "cssnano": "^3.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.5.1",
    "grunt-postcss": "^0.8.0",
    "grunt-sass": "^2.0.0",
    "pixrem": "^4.0.1"
  }
}
```

project dependencies package.json

```
{
  "name": "project-Dependencies-package-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "some-internal-js-project": "1.1.2",
    "tablesorter": "~2.18.4",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "html5shiv": "^3.7.3",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jquery-dotdotdot": "^1.8.2",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "jquery-ui-dist": "^1.12.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.3",
    "respond.js": "^1.4.2",
    "tooltipster": "^4.2.5",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7"
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround**: Remove all arguments from Step 3's goal.

Having a working directory different from the other goal (Step 2) suffices to place the "project dependencies" NPM artifacts in a folder other than the artifacts from Step 2 ("build tool dependencies").

I would still like to understand what went wrong in the first place / what I did wrong?

```
<execution>
    <id>install compass js dependencies</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>npm</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <workingDirectory>src/main/javascript/dependencies</workingDirectory>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```